# How to create a JWT?

Tags: javascript, json, netsuite, suitescript

I am working on a script to dynamically create a JWT for a google api call when a customer record is edited/created in NetSuite. I have been able to successfully call the api from a script with a manually created JWT. This script will create a new JWT for every call, this is needed because a JWT is only active for 1 hour after creation, the issue I am running into is correctly encoding an object. The documentation I found on SuiteAnswers only referenced encoding strings, and I am not totally sure how the encoding process works when done manually. (if the entire object is stringified or if it is broken up)

This is the piece of code with the object (payload) needing to be encoded correctly to finish creating the JWT.

````
var secondsSinceEpoch = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000)

var plusOneHour = secondsSinceEpoch + 3600

var payload = {
   "target_audience": "https://sample.com",
   "iss": "sample.com",
   "sub": "sample.com",
   "exp": plusOneHour,
   "iat": secondsSinceEpoch,
   "aud": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
}

log.debug({
   title:'payload',
   details: JSON.stringify(payload)});

var base64EncodedString = encode.convert({
   string: JSON.stringify(payload),
   inputEncoding: encode.Encoding.UTF_8,
   outputEncoding: encode.Encoding.BASE_64_URL_SAFE});

return connectToGCP(base64EncodedString)```
````

Comment: It was generating JWTs correctly, unfortunately the system I was trying to connect to did not have the correct security permissions and so I ended up having to go a different route. But this code definitely helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use public/private keys for signing your solution would look something like:

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 */

 define(['N/encode', 'N/crypto'], function(encode, crypto){

   function signIt(payload, ttl){


      if(typeof payload.exp == 'undefined'){
         var secondsSinceEpoch = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
         var expAt = secondsSinceEpoch + (ttl || 60); 
         payload["exp"] = expAt;
         payload["iat"] = secondsSinceEpoch;
      }

      log.debug({
         title:'payload',
         details: JSON.stringify(payload)});

      function toB64(str){
         return encode.convert({
          string: str,
          inputEncoding: encode.Encoding.UTF_8,
          outputEncoding: encode.Encoding.BASE_64_URL_SAFE}).replace(/=+$/, '');
      }
    
       var header = toB64(JSON.stringify({
             type:'JWT',
             alg:'HS256'
          }));
    
       var body = toB64( JSON.stringify(payload));
    
       var mySecret = 'custsecret_jwt_sample_secret';    //secret id take from secrets management page
    
       var sKey = crypto.createSecretKey({
          secret: mySecret,
          encoding: encode.Encoding.UTF_8
       });
    
       var signer = crypto.createHmac({
          algorithm: crypto.HashAlg.SHA256,
          key:sKey
       });
    
       signer.update({
          input:header +'.'+ body,
          inputEncoding: encode.Encoding.UTF_8
       });
    
       var sig = signer.digest({
          outputEncoding:encode.Encoding.BASE_64_URL_SAFE
       }).replace(/=+$/, '');
    
       return  [header, body, sig].join('.');
   }

   return {
      signIt: signIt
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you bknights, the header and signature parts of the JWT I need to make wont ever change so those are hardcoded in another function. So those are taken care of, would I still need to put the payload object thru this process? (your code above)

Comment: The payload changes every time because iat and exp change every time. Since the signature is a hash of the header and payload it also changes every time. So yes this is the process to create the JWT.

Comment: No worries. If this works for you please mark the answer as accepted otherwise let us know what errors you get.

Comment: Hello,

This was a conversion from some SS1 code but didn't actually work. Current sample does work and produces a token that I verified with one of the standard verified libraries (jsonwebtoken)

Comment: Did this end up being helpful? If so please mark the answer as accepted so others will be able to benefit from it.